# First column of GridView readonly unless new row

Tags: vb.net, gridview, devexpress, basic, devexpress-gridcontrol

I have a GridView with various columns and rows pulled from a database.

In the first column I have a dateEdit repository item.

What I would like to do is have this first column readonly for all rows except when the user clicks "Add new row" as the user will need to edit the date on new rows.

I have been trying using the [ShowingEditor()](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.ShowingEditor) event and e.Cancel however this makes the whole row readonly and not just the first column (the rows have other repository items like TextEdits).

I am using DevExpress with Visual Basic and Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [`ShowingEditor`](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.ShowingEditor) event you can use [`FocusedColumn`](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.FocusedColumn) property to set `e.Cancel = True` only for particular columns.

```
If YourGridView.FocusedColumn.FieldName = "YourDateEditColumn" Then
    e.Cancel = True
    Exit Sub
End If
```